# jquery - Add field dynamically not functioning fully

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, field

based on tutorial from [here](http://www.codexworld.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery/) ,I'm trying to make some fields which can dynamically be added by a button an removed by another button. It almost works fine except that another group of fields that supposed to be created dynamically as well is not adding anything.

Here's what i did at [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAmPAV).

```
    <div class="field_wrapper">    
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">New Group</a>  
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field">X</a><table id="add_on_table"><tbody><tr><td><label class="field">Group Name</label><input type="text" name="product_addon_name[]"></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="product_addon_required[]"> Mark as Required</td></tr><tr><td><label class="field">Group Description </label><textarea name="product_addon_description[]"></textarea></td></tr><tr><table><thead><tr><td>Option Label</td><td>Option Price (RM) </td></tr></thead><tbody class="addonoption"><tr><td><input type="text" name="product_addon_option_label[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="product_addon_option_price[]"></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_row" title="Remove field">X</a></td></tr> </tbody><tfoot><tr><td><input type="button" class="add_option" value="New Option"></td></tr></tfoot></table></tr></tbody></table></div>'; //New input field html 
    var AddRow = $('.add_option'); //Add button selector
    var RowWrapper = $('.addonoption'); //Input field wrapper
    var rowHTML = '<tr> <td><input type="text" name="product_addon_option_label[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="product_addon_option_price[]"></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_row" title="Remove field">X</a></td></tr>';    
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1   
    $(AddRow).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked     
      $(RowWrapper).append(rowHTML); // Add field html           
    });
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
          $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    }); 
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
    });</script>
```

In reference to what I did in the linked codepen, the fields generated OK when pressed the 'New Group' link. However, the button 'New Option' does not create anything once clicked. You can see in the JS section i write some code to create field, but it's just not working. Any idea why? Btw, i'm quite noob at javascript/jquery, so, sorry if it's just a stupid mistake. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) with the `.add_option` elements too. Since they are created after the DOM is initially rendered, your click handler does not attach to anything. You use event delegation for the `.remove_button`, so you can copy that syntax to make it work:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_option", function(){ //Once add button is clicked  
    $(this).closest("table").find(".addonoption").append(rowHTML);         
});
```

Also, I noticed that your selector is potentially messed up too because if you have multiple groups, it will add the html to each one of them. If this is the intended behavior, you can change the selector to `$(".addonoption").append(rowHTML)`, otherwise, the above code will work for you!

Comment: thanks a bunch! combining with Lajos Arpad answer, it worked well!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you try to add a click handler to AddRow, your button does not exist yet. Instead of creating a handler to AddRow, you need to use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `function`. Example:

```
$(".field_wrapper").on("click", ".add_option", function() {alert("foo");});
```

Explanation:

- `.field_wrapper` as a selector already exists when you call `on`
- `click` is the event you intend to handle
- `.add_option` is a selector which will apply to existent and not yet existent elements inside `.field_wrapper` that match `.add_option`
- the `function` is the event handler to be executed